# Where are Git branches after hard reset?

Tags: git

I was having problems with my code so I rolled back to the last commit using this command:

```
git reset --hard <7-digit-hash>
```

Now when I issue the command "git branch" I just see my current branch, not my master branch and another branch I had.  What happened to them?  Is there some way to change things so that I continue seeing all my branches like before?  My code problem goes away with this branch that I've reverted to so I'd like to keep it, commit it, and push it back up to my remote.  What is going on here?  How do I do these two things?  The git branch documentation didn't really explain what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check the output of `git status`, and of `git branch -avv`: that should give you more visibility in your current state.

If anything (commit, branch, tag) is missing in a git repo, check also **[`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)**: you would get them back there.

If you had your current branch checked out, its HEAD was properly reset to the SHA1 you mentioned, so this part is fine.

Comment: Thanks.  git status didn't tell me anything useful.  I did do "git branch -avv" and I could see my local "dev" branch (the one I was working on) and remotes/origin/HEAD, dev, and master.  I then did "git co master" to make sure my master branch (which dev is a descendent of) was still there and it said "Switched to a new branch 'master'" which worries me.  Did git create an entirely *new* master branch instead of switching to my original master branch?  That would be really bad. I just want to commit dev that has my reverted working code and then merge dev back into my original master.

Comment: @Dave did you see master or origin/master? Again, if you had a local master branch, you would still see it in git reflog.

Comment: @Dave It sounds like you somehow deleted your local copy of `master`. When you did `git co master`, you created a new local branch named `master` which is at the same location as `origin/master` which is called a "remote tracking branch". In other words, it is a local copy of `master` in your remote repository. If you did a `git push` before deleting your local `master` branch, then `origin/master` is at the same commit as `master`. You can use `git log --all --oneline --decorate` to see where each branch is.

Answer (score 2):

`git reset` only affects the current branch. Even then, it only moves teh branch. It will not delete it. Nor will it delete any other branches.

Somehow you deleted local copy of `master` with some other command. When you did `git co master`, you created a new local branch named `master` which is at the same location as `origin/master`. To understand the branches under `origin/`, you need to learn more about so-called "remote tracking branches". These are local copies of the branches in a remote repository. Note that they are **local copies**. They are updated when you perform commands which interact with the remote such as `git push`, `git pull`, or `git fetch`.

If you did a `git push` before deleting your local `master` branch, then `origin/master` is at the same commit as `master`. You can use `git log --all --oneline --decorate` to see where each branch is. This will help you know if `master` is back at the correct commit. Since `dev` was already ahead of your original `master`, it will contain all of the commits. If you want to move `master`, you can use `git checkout master` and `git reset --hard <SHA1>` to do so.